# $x_k=y_k=k$ for $k≤31$ and $x_{k+1}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3…+x_k}{k}$ for $k≥31$, $y_{k+1}=\frac{y_k+y_{k-1}+y_{k-2}…+y_{k-30}}{31}$ for $k≥31$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

$x_k=k$ for $k≤31$

$x_{k+1}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3…+x_k}{k}$ for $k≥31$

$y_k=x_k$ for $k≤31$

$y_{k+1}=\frac{y_k+y_{k-1}+y_{k-2}…+y_{k-30}}{31}$ for $k≥31$

Find $\lim_{k \to \infty}(y_k-x_k)$

By substituting $k=32,33…$ I was able to be easily find that $x_k=16$ for all $k≥32$. But I am not able to think of where to start for $y_k$, any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Ask yourself, Is $y_{k+1} \geq 1$ ?

Comment: @BranBur yes it is >15

Comment: @dxiv though I've corrected it now I made a pretty major typing error in the question in the expression for $y_{k+1}$. Should I post the corrected question again? And delete this post

Comment: @l1mbo I removed my previous comment since it no longer applies. Think it's fine to leave the corrected question here, since there were no answers posted, yet. But you should fix the title, too.